# geometric Brownian motion and the weak efficient market hypothesis

Tags: martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

I want to show that the assumption that stock prices follow geometric Brownian motion is consistent with the weak efficient market hypothesis. I first want to show that the stock price defined by the following SDE is a martingale.
\begin{equation}
 d S_t=\mu S_tdt+\sigma S_td B_t\label{jhblyd}
\end{equation}
By ITO's formula,
\begin{equation*}
   d\ln {S_t} = \left( {\frac{1}{{{S_t}}}\mu {S_t} + \frac{{ - 1}}{2}\frac{1}{{{S_t}^2}}{\sigma ^2}{S_t}^2} \right)dt + \frac{1}{{{S_t}}}\sigma {S_t}d{B_t} = \left( {\mu  - \frac{1}{2}{\sigma ^2}} \right)dt + \sigma d{B_t}
   %\label{dlnst}
  \end{equation*}
Integrate with respect to $t$,
\begin{equation*}
   \begin{aligned}
   \ln {S_t} &= \ln S_0+\int_{0}^t\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)ds+\int_0^t\sigma dB_s\\
   & = \ln S_0+\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma B_t.
   \end{aligned}
  \end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation}
   S_t=S_0e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma B_t}.
  \end{equation}
$S_t$ is a martingale if and only if $\mu=0$.

So when the drift rate is not equal to zero, is that a violation of the weak efficient market hypothesis?

Comment: These formulas are better known than the weak efficient market hypothesis. What exactly is that?

Comment: The weak efficient market hypothesis refers to the fact that the price of a stock has fully incorporated the information contained in the historical share price. Under this assumption, stock prices have martingale properties.@KurtG.

Comment: If the converse does not hold the answer to your question is then obviously no.

Comment: Yes, seen from my work, the stock price sequence is not a martingale (unless the drift rate is zero), but the textbook says it is a martingale, such as this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1737119/907140. Puzzled.

Comment: If you just want to know if it is a martingale (or more typically the discounted stock price) we neither need a textbook nor do we need a weak efficient market hypothesis. All we need to know is what filtration applies. That of the BM obviously. And correct. It is not a martingale for every $\mu.$

Comment: Could you please further explain the sentence that "filtration applies to BM"? What is "BM" stand for? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: BM means the Brownian motion. I read a bit the other post and about [EMH](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient-market_hypothesis) in the mean time. EMH deals with empirical research of real stock prices. In contrast, your equations are only the simplest stock price *model* of them all. This model is as you know a martingale if and only if $\mu=0$. That's all. A model cannot violate a statement about real markets.

Comment: After your reminder, I realize that my previous measure of testing EMH was too simple. I'll take a closer look. Thank you very much.